# Firefox and Chromium don't recognize Windows and Mac fonts after updates

Tags: 16.04, firefox, fonts, chromium

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have noticed that after each update of the system, firefox and chromium browsers are not recognizing  previously installed fonts  (Windows and Mac fonts).

Is there any way to make those browsers recognize those fonts again? I tried  `sudo fc-cache -f -v` but no effect. My fonts have installed in `/usr/share/fonts`.

The fonts are Arabic fonts. I don't know if this is related to the issue.

The website which changes appearance after updating is facebook.com. e.g the post fonts are not as usual.

Comment: From a technical viewpoint, all the files in your home directory will not be touched during an OS update. This fact contains the answer to your question: Since, under Linux, programs generally store their settings in hidden directories under ~/.(dotfiles), the settings will be kept.

Comment: Yes.  Fonts folders and files still the same, but for some reason the browsers not finding them! I know this, when I inspect for example a paragraph to see its css styles, it put a  line-through on the font-family.

Comment: My understanding is that browser fonts are defined by the CSS of the visited pages.

Comment: Ok, it's defined by webpages, but should be exist in the system, otherwise, it will downgrade to the another installed font and this may corrupt the page design.